# What tag should be used for [bureaucracy]?

Tags: discussion, tags

A [question of mine](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15599/do-the-the-census-bureau-and-the-irs-of-the-usa-employ-or-consult-theolgians) was recently migrated from the Christianity SE, and I joined Politics to be able to fully follow it. In the migration, it lost its tags. (You guys don't seem to discuss [non-denominationalism].  ) Since the question involves government agencies, I thought [bureaucracy] would be a good fit, but it does not exist.  What would be a good substitute? I ended up with [united-states] [religion], which were not bad, but I still would have liked to bring in the governmental aspect.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Politics.SE.

I would suggest to name the tag [public-administration](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-administration) because it is [the academic name for the science of bureaucracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_administration).

Comment: Thank you for making and applying the tag, Philipp. I agree with [public-administration] as the primary name, but I suggest [bureaucracy] be added as a synonym. When I was searching the tags, the former is not a name I thought to find, and with 13 pages to search thru it is not necessarily something one's eyes would catch.